# Return to another part of a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and I cannot figure out how to get back to a certain part of loop depending on the response.

If it reaches:

```
else :  
   print('Answer must be yes or no')
```

I want it to start back at:

```
print ("We are going to add numbers.")
```

I have tried several different suggestions I have seen on here, but they result in starting back at the very beginning.

My code:

```
import random
num1 = random.randint(1,100)
num2 = random.randint(1,100)
addition = num1 + num2 
print("Hello. What is your name?")
name = str(input())

print ("Nice to meet you " + name)
print ("We are going to add numbers.")
print ("Does that sound good?")
answer = str.lower(input())

if answer == str('yes'):
    print ('Yay!!')
    print ('Add these numbers')
    print (num1,  num2)
    numbers = int(input())
    if numbers == addition:    
        print('Good Job!')
    else:
        print('Try again')
        numbers = int(input())

elif answer == str('no'):
    print ('Goodbye')


else :
    print('Answer must be yes or no')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop that starts with the thing you want to get back to:

```
def start():
    import random
    num1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 100)
    addition = num1 + num2
    print("Hello. What is your name?")
    name = str(input())

    print("Nice to meet you " + name)
    while True:
        print("We are going to add numbers.")
        print("Does that sound good?")
        answer = str.lower(input())
        if answer == "no":
            print("Goodbye")
            return
        elif answer == "yes":
            break
        else:
            print('Answer must be yes or no')

    print('Yay!!')
    print('Add these numbers')
    print(num1, num2)

    # This following part might want to be a loop too?
    numbers = int(input())
    if numbers == addition:
        print('Good Job!')
    else:
        print('Try again')
        numbers = int(input())
```

Comment: Thanks! I will see what I can do. I am very new at this. The tutorials I was using helped to a point, but I did not feel like I was retaining as much as I needed to. So, I figured I would try what I know and expand on that through the tutorials, google, and here.